# Define values for each namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

values.yaml

```
replicas: {
  test: 1,
  stage: 2,
  prod: 3
}
```

Here I am trying to use Helm templates to define number of replicas per namespace but am unsure of the proper syntax and pattern:

deployment.yaml

```
replicas: {{ .Values.replicas.{{ .Release.Namespace }} }}
```

So if this were deployed to `--namespace=prod`, I would expect the template to return:

```
# .Values.replicas.prod
replicas: 3
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you wish to get from the template?

Comment: Have a look at helmfile (https://github.com/roboll/helmfile), it offers you perfect solution for this kind of usecase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the template functions provided by the standard Go [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) library are available.  In particular, that includes an `index` function which can do dynamic lookup in an array or map object.

```
replicas: {{ index .Values.replicas .Release.Namespace }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Helm supports evaluating variable in the variable. For this, you're expression would need to be evaluated twice.

What you could do is to write the following code:

```
{{ if eq .Release.Namespace "test" }}{{ .Values.replicas.test }}{{ end }}
```

You can then also extract that code to your `_helpers.tpl`. Then the usage should be clear and pretty.