# Reference value key with different value in helm/go template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to know if it's possible to use a value as an object key of a different value like this?

```
...
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values[.Release.Namespace].replicas }}
...
```

When my `values.yaml` is like:

```
production:
  replicas: 2
staging:
  replicas: 1
```

And I install like this:

```
helm install --namespace production my-release .
```

If not, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: there is the --set flag as well, this is what I use when I need to make dev|prod distinctions

Comment: @JoshBeauregard I want to use the `values.yaml` defaults, and not set every time I upgrade

Comment: so you dont want to override the charts default values?

Comment: @JoshBeauregard this is my chart, I set the defaults and I want to set the default behaviour, however, the syntax is not correct. What I'm asking is how to use the namespace as a key for the value of replicas

Comment: That question suggests the `index` template function, though its values layout is slightly different from yours; `{{ index (index .Values .Release.Namespace) "replicas" }}` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look at similar case: [helm-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348814/define-values-for-each-namespace).
You use the index template function, though its values layout is little bit different from yours; 
`{{ index (index .Values .Release.Namespace) "replicas" }}` should work.

You can use more than one value file when installing a [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts). You can have a "default" values.yaml, and then have several values.env.yaml files with the specific settings for each environment.

You could iterate over the "namespaces" and use the one that matches the current namespace.

Comment: Down voted because this is all copied from @Ángela's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use more than one value file when installing a helm chart. You can have a "default" values.yaml, and then have several values.env.yaml files with the specific settings for each environment.

So you would have:

values.yaml

```
someConfigForAllEnvironments: true
```

values.staging.yaml

```
replicas: 1
```

values.production.yaml

```
replicas: 2
```

template.yaml

```
...
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
...
```

And you would install with:

```
helm install --namespace production my-release -f values.production.yaml
```

Comment: There has got to be a way to reference an object inside `values.yaml` with a different value like namespace, all in 1 file.

Comment: You could iterate over the "namespaces" and use the one that matches the current namespace, but that won't be pretty