# Use variable value with .Values in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've below parameters in values.yaml. I need to fetch the value of the schema but the database name may change

```
  preparedDatabases:
    a3s:
      schemas:
        a3s:
```

I'm using below functions in tpl  to return the databasename and the schema name.

```
{{/* Return Databasename
*/}}
{{- define "databasename" }}
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.spec.preparedDatabases -}}
{{- $key | toYaml | trim }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}


{{/* Return Schemaname
*/}}
{{- define "schema" }}
{{- $dbname := include "databasename" . }}
{{- range $key, $val := ( .Values.spec.preparedDatabases.{{ $dbname }}.schemas)  -}}
{{- $key | toYaml | trim }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

But it returns the error `bad character U+0024 '$'`

Could you please help on how can i interpret the variable dbname to be used with .Values

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define values for each namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348814/define-values-for-each-namespace)